# remove space from bars in apexChart

Tags: apexcharts

It is possible to remove the space between bars currently using apex chart[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxa0N.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set column width to `100%` in `plotOptions`

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    columnWidth: "100%"
  }
},
```